# Express-Session not saving sessions after refresh

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, express-session

I've been trying to find a solution about why isn't my sessions saving and any source that I read couldn't help me, so I think it would be best to ask for the sulition why isn't my session saving this is the code I have right now.

```
const Express = require("express")
const Path = require("path")
const Session = require("express-session")
const CookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const MemoryStore = require("memorystore")(Session)

const App = Express()
const AccountRouter = require("./Controller/Account.js")
const MainRouter = require("./Controller/Main.js")
const APIHandler = require("./Controller/APIHandler.js")


const OneMonth = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;


App.use(CookieParser())
App.set("view engine", "pug")
App.set('views', Path.join(__dirname, 'Pages'));
App.use('/Utils', Express.static(Path.join(__dirname, 'Utils')))

App.use(Session({
    cookie: { maxAge: OneMonth },
    store: new MemoryStore({
      checkPeriod: OneMonth
    }),
    resave: false,
    secret: 'secret'
}))
```

And this is how I am saving it

```
                Request.session.TokenID = Token
                console.log(Request.session.TokenID);
                Request.session.save();
```

At first it saves Request.session.TokenID does print out the token id but after the refresh everything gets deleted.

```
        MySQL(`SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username = "${Body.Username}"`, function(Data) {
            if (Data.length > 0) {
                Response.send("Username taken.").status(200)
                return
            }

            if (!Body.Password) {
                Response.send("Please type the password.").status(200)
                return
            }
        
            if (!Body.Firstname) {
                Response.send("Please type the firstname.").status(200)
                return
            }
        
            if (!Body.Lastname) {
                Response.send("Please type the lastname.").status(200)
                return
            }
        
            if (String.toString(Body.Password).length < 8) {
                Response.send("Password must be at least 8 characters long.").status(200)
                return
            }
        
            if (String.toString(Body.Password).length < 5) {
                Response.send("Username must be at least 5 characters long.").status(200)
                return
            }

            var Firstname = CapitalizeFirstLetter(Body.Firstname)
            var Lastname = CapitalizeFirstLetter(Body.Lastname)
            var Password = Hash(Body.Password)
            var Token = TokenGenerator(50)
            var Status = 0
            var Balance = 0.00
            var Username = CapitalizeFirstLetter(Body.Username)

            MySQL(`INSERT INTO Accounts 
            (Firstname, Lastname, Password, Token, Status, Balance, Username) 
            VALUES 
            ('${Firstname}','${Lastname}','${Password}','${Token}','${Status}','${Balance}','${Username}')`, (Callback) => {
                Request.session.TokenID = Token
                console.log(Request.session.TokenID);
                Request.session.save();
            })
        })
```

Comment: You need not call `req.session.save()`, it will be automatically saved by `res.end` or similar. Can you share the rest of your middleware code?

Comment: Here I added a little bit more code at the end.

Comment: Where is the `res.send` or similar in your code? It must come after (or rather: instead of) the `Request.session.save()`.

Comment: is it necessary when saving sessions?
Because I didn't do it right now for testing purposes.

Comment: Well, after I added Response.send("OK") it saved thanks.